# Дать возможность пользователю загружать YouTube видео с сайта

Tags: javascript

На сайте есть Youtube видео, нужно поместить на плеере кнопку, при нажатии на которую пользователь сможет загружать себе видео. Есть ли возможность реализовать загрузку на компьютер/телефон видео файла с youtub-а, не используя сторонних библиотек?